# SQL Query that contains a URL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the query below. I want to receive records that doesn't include `mywebsite.com/url` but that includes `mywebsite.comurl`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM [mydb].[dbo].[mytable] 
WHERE No is not null 
AND Thumbnail is not null 
AND Thumbnail not like '<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://www.mywebsite.com/%'
```

When I run the query, it gives me an unexpected number. What is wrong with the query, how can I make it work correctly?

Comment: "unexpected number", you mean it matches an incorrect number of rows? If so then you need to debug, look at rows it included or did not include, that is incorrect, and see if you can spot the problem.

Comment: Obviously the first step is to remove the count and look at the actual individual rows returned. Really. Troubleshooting 101

Comment: Show sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [mydb].[dbo].[mytable] WHERE No is not null
 AND Thumbnail is not null
 AND Thumbnail like '%mywebsite.com%'
 AND Thumbnail not like '%mywebsite.com/url%'
```